# How to get the unix timestamp from UIDatePicker

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How to get the unix timestamp from UIDatePicker

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
UIDatePicker *picker = ...;
NSTimeInterval t = [picker.date timeIntervalSince1970];
```

You can subsequently use the `NSTimeInterval` as a numeric primitive type, which at the time of writing is a `double`. You may want to cast it to an `int` explicitly, depending on the use case.